# How to mark column value found False as zero | Excel | Conditional formatting |

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have a scenario where i want to mark the value as zero if found to be FALSE

Below is my table of data

[image: my data in excel sheet]

in above image if you see the column 4 => cell C4 as one 'FALSE' value and correspond to that B4 cell as Blank value

i need to set that B4 value to zero.

Note : need to search the column 4 to find false keyword and correspond to that the B column cell value is blank it need to be set as numeric value Zero

how to do it using conditional formatting

**my below code**

```
=ISNUMBER(C4='FALSE' then B4 set to zero)
```

Answer (score 0):

My first post, so be gentle please.

I am pretty sure that you could do that with conditional formatting, but I can think of simpler options. Is it required that you use conditional formatting, or do you need to get it done?

You could use Find & Replace functionality. Just select the range - which will be the whole column or part of it in your case, click Ctrl+H, go to the second tab (find and replace), leave the find field blank and write number 0 in replace field, then hit replace button until you feel all is done.

You could do that with a function as well, but I think that should do the job. I will check this post tomorrow as well, so feel free to comment.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if conditional formatting can set a value. Conditional formatting as the name suggest is used to set the "Formatting".

To address your need, here is what I would do:-

1. Create a new column called "RollNumber" and rename the old one as "Old RollNumber"
2. In the new column, i.e. cell `B2` type the formula `=IF(ISNUMBER(C2),C2,0)`
3. Copy the formula through to the bottom of the table (now this will apply to all)

[Before hiding column C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBC8t.png)

4. Hide column `C` this will hide the "Old RollNumber" column

[After hiding the column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNJ7E.png)

Hope that helps.